# Sending push notfications to multiple devices using this code (PHP)

Tags: java, php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm new to GCM / Java, I'm experienced in php, but only mysql.

I found this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

It was very useful, and I got it to work. My only problem is that this code is for sending to one device at a time.
I tryed to edit it so it sends to multiple devices using one form & one submit button, but without a success.

This code gets from Java (Client) Info and puts it in a mysql database using php (Server). 
It also registers the GCM registration id of the device in the mysql DB,
and than you can send notifications by id to the device using the id's GCM reg id.

Here is the index.php where you fill in the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

            });
            function sendPushNotification(id){
                var data = $('form#'+id).serialize();
                $('form#'+id).unbind('submit');                
                $.ajax({
                    url: "send_message.php",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend: function() {

                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                          $('.txt_message').val("");

                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container{
                width: 950px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0;
            }
            h1{
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 24px;
                color: #777;
            }
            div.clear{
                clear: both;
            }
            ul.devices{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            ul.devices li{
                float: left;
                list-style: none;
                border: 1px solid #dedede;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 0 15px 25px 0;
                border-radius: 3px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #555;
            }
            ul.devices li label, ul.devices li span{
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-style: normal;
                font-variant: normal;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #393939;
                display: block;
                float: left;
            }
            ul.devices li label{
                height: 25px;
                width: 50px;                
            }
            ul.devices li textarea{
                float: left;
                resize: none;
            }
            ul.devices li .send_btn{
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0096FF), to(#005DFF));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0096FF), to(#005DFF));
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #0096FF, #005DFF);
                background: linear-gradient(#0096FF, #005DFF);
                text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                border-radius: 3px;
                color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include_once 'db_functions.php';
        $db = new DB_Functions();
        $users = $db->getAllUsers();
        if ($users != false)
            $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
        else
            $no_of_users = 0;
        ?>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>No of Devices Registered: <?php echo $no_of_users; ?></h1>
            <hr/>
            <ul class="devices">
                <?php
                if ($no_of_users > 0) {
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <form id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" name="" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPushNotification('<?php echo $row["id"] ?>')">
                                <label>Name: </label> <span><?php echo $row["name"] ?></span>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <label>Email:</label> <span><?php echo $row["klas"] ?></span>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <div class="send_container">                                
                                    <textarea rows="3" name="message" cols="25" class="txt_message" placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row["gcm_regid"] ?>"/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Send" onclick=""/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    <?php }
                } else { ?> 
                    <li>
                        No Users Registered Yet!
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's using ajax to send it to GCM:

Send_message.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['regId']) && (isset($_GET["message"]))) {


    $regId = $_GET['regId'];
    $message = $_GET["message"];

    include_once './GCM.php';

    $gcm = new GCM();

    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
    $message = array("price" => $message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
}
?>
```

As you see, it gets everthing by id, 
but I want to use one form, one submit button & one text field to send to multiple devices.

Would really appreciate it if someone could instruct me how to do it or give me some examples.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know php, but `GCM.php` from the link you provided seems to already support sending push notifications to multiple devices :

```
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    // include config
    include_once './config.php';

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );
```

You should simply pass to the `send_notification` function an array that contains multiple Registration IDs, and it would send notifications to all of them.

Comment: Thnx, but i did already solve it^^ , Next time i post myself a answer to help other people out. I don't got the specific code here now, i update this later.

Comment: What is the code, I am stuck on the exact same thing.